# Cramers rule and inverse in complex numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Ok so my teacher defined the complex number system by saing it is RxR and defined $(a,b)*(c,d)=ac-bd,ad+bc)$

the multiplicative identity is (1,0) and he asked us to find the multiplicative inverse of (a,b) denoted $(a,b)^{-1}$. He told me to use Cramer. My approach was to use the fact that if $(a,b)^{-1}=(x,y)$ then $ax-by=1$ and $bx+ay=0$. (I can't see an easy way to solve this) I guess this is where cramer comes in but i cant see how to use it since neither of those eqations is linear).

Regards.

Comment: $(a,b)$ is fixed, so both equations are linear in $(x,y)$. $$\begin{pmatrix}a & -b\\ b&a \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Daniel's solution also demonstrates the awesome fact that $\mathbb C$ embeds in $M_2\mathbb R$ as a ring, via
$$(a+ib) = (a,b) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean $(a,c) \cdot (b,d) = (ac - bd, ad + bc)$.

$\begin {bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

By cramers rule:

$x = \frac {\begin{Vmatrix} 1 & -b \\ 0 & a \end{Vmatrix}} {\begin{Vmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\end{Vmatrix}} = \frac {a} {a^2 + b^2}$

$y = \frac {\begin{Vmatrix} a & 1 \\ b & 0 \end{Vmatrix}} {\begin{Vmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\end{Vmatrix}} = \frac {-b} {a^2 + b^2}$